# Would using step-up and step-down converters in the same circuitry damage the battery?

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, step-down

One of my projects, to be powered by 2S Lithium Ion batteries (7.4V), requires various voltages, such as 3.3V, 5V and 12V, to be derived using a couple of step-down and a step-up converter.

I am apprehensive on the use of a step-up converter after the negative feedback I have received.

However I would like go ahead and use it based on the advice of more experienced people in this forum.

Details of the step-up converter are accessible here.[MT3608](https://www.olimex.com/Products/Breadboarding/BB-PWR-3608/resources/MT3608.pdf)

Comment: My opinion: they are incorrect.

Comment: also, unless your friends have any arguments, I'd say: this is not a technical question. There's step up converters, many of these will even have datasheets that show explicitly how to use them with a battery and a battery doesn't care – all things you probably know. So, nothing really to answer here: as Andy says, your friends are wrong, and you shouldn't listen to them :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for your answer. I changed the link for the datasheet in the question (MT2608). There is no problem with the battery or the circuitry itself. But, I only wanted to cover why using a dc-dc step-up converter would be that efficient or kind of not preferable! I don't have solid knowledge of power electronics really.

Comment: your title implies you worry about damage, which is not the same as inefficiency. But anyway, if you need a higher voltage than your battery can offer, what other choice do you have than to step up your voltage?

Comment: you haven't told us anything about the currents required at different voltages. The step up converter will work fine if your requirements are modest enough.